# how do i pipe to response from an api get request in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const request = require('request');
app.get('/dat', function(req, res){
let options = {
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=bee&limit=1&format=json'

};
request(options).pipe(res);
console.log(res);
 });
 app.listen(8000);
```

How do I get data from response object in the above code ? I have tried logging response it gives me output but i just want data from response object via pipe function.

Comment: The `.pipe(res)` you're doing should work.  You can't log the response like you are.  `console.log(res)` just shows you the `res` stream object, not the results of your `request()`.  `.pipe()` will stream it to the res object.  What do you get on the other end?

Comment: so should i use something like:

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    res.send(chunk);
});

Comment: No, your `.pipe()` is the right way to do it.  You could `res.write(chunk)` (can't use `res.send()` multiple times and then follow it with a `res.send()`, but that's not necessary.   `.pipe()` does all the work for you and will handle lots of details for you.

Comment: Note that you could `.pipe()` to multiple writeable streams if you want as well (e.g. `stdout` and `res`), but there [are a few gotchas](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2817-the-affect-of-back-pressure-when-piping-data-into-multiple-writable-streams-in-node-js.htm).